# c# azure mobile services html upload picture

Tags: c#, html, azure, mobile, service

I want to upload a photo from an HTML form post to an Azure Mobile Service written in C#. The issue is that I need to check a security token as well. All of the sample code that I have seen involves uploading to Blob Storage, but I don't want to do that - I need to process the image.

Ideally, I would have a method signature something like this:

> void PostMyPicture(string token, byte[] image)

but that method doesn't get dispatched to. I confirmed with Fiddler that the post is happening correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Blob storage because images use a lot of traffic and Azure Mobile Services as a limit of size in the requests. I think will be hard to find sample using AMS that do what you want, but maybe you use a solution for WebAPI that works in AMS.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I guess that I could do that, but it makes my web client work harder, which is my objection. The web client would have to request an SAS, then upload to the new URL. I would rather keep this simple on the client side.